# TextView not updating TEXT

Tags: android, android-fragments, textview

I have looked at almost all the posts on stack but haven't found anything like my problem. I have a `fragment` in a `viewpager`, and in that fragment there is an class, lets call it `customClass`. I start an activity from the `fragment`, which returns a value to the onActivityResult of the fragment. Inside it I call a method of customClass which updates a `textView` with the data retrieved from the `onActivityResault` bundle.

**Fragment**

```
public class clock_fragment extends Fragment {

    customClass myClass;

    public clock_fragment() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_clock, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if(item.getItemId() == R.id.menu_settings) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SettingsActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);


        myClass = new customClass();
        myClass.initializeValues(this, view);

    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, final Intent data) {
        if (resultCode != RESULT_CANCELED) {

            myClass.updateTextView(data.getStringExtra("currency", "fail"));

        }
    }
}
```

**customClass**

```
public class myClass {

    final String TAG = "TAG";
    Fragment fragment;
    TextView textView;

    public myClass() {

    }


    public void initializeValues(clock_fragment f, View view) {
        fragment = f;
        textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);

    }


    public void updateTextView(String value) {

        textView.setText(value);

        //i can change its colour
        textView.setTextColor(fragment.getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.yellow));

        //i can print out its updated value, not the one being shown on the screen
        Log.e(TAG, "updateCurrencyFromPreferences: "+textView.getText());
    }
}
```

All the methods are **called** fine, everything executes. I can even print out the `string` value in a log and it gives me the desired result, in all methods. The text view **text DOES change**, proved by a using `textView.getText()` and printing it in a log message i put in the end of `updateTextView(String value)`.

BUT the `textView` doesn't update its text! I've tried so many things. I've considered it could have to do with the fragment not having the same `textView` reference because its being recreated after I start the `activity` and then return back.

I can even change the `textColour` of the `textView` (in `updateTextView` method) and that also works normally, I can see it happening, though the text doesn't change. I've also tried changing the text to some random dummy text but no luck. As i said printing a log messege with `textView.getText()` shows the updated text in the log, but it doesn't match up with whats on screen (text doesnt change). I've even tried passing the `textView` from the main fragment to that specific method but alas no luck. pls help :'D

PS: The custom class already has a reference to the `textView` that is created from a view passed into the contructer. EVERYTHING Works, no errors or assignment issues, just the text **doesn't** update.

I will be happy to provide more information if this isn't enough.

Comment: It sounds like `customClass` has a reference to a different `TextView` than the one which is actually displayed in the `Activity`. Please show more of this class. In particular, how is `textView` declared and initialized? How is the `customClass` variable in your activity created and initialized?

Comment: That could be part of the issue. if that is the case then why can i still change the colour? and even get its updated text? I will edit my question to give you more information

Comment: How do you change the color? Please show more code.

Comment: The code you post here should be valid Java. In particular, all methods should be in a class just like it is in your actual code and you should show declarations for all fields that are used in your methods.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice done.

Comment: did you try using `runUiThread()`?

Comment: Yes I've tried, i replied to an answer that suggested that but it got deleted

Answer (score 3):

the code u provided is just a sample, please make sure that the `setText()` in your project is called in the main thread.

if there're still some problems, u can try to update text with posting a delay runnabe.

Comment: How would i do it with the delayed runnable? I've already tried runOnaUIThread

Comment: just like this: 
`new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {setText();}, 1000);`

Comment: This seems to work, i can even set 0s delay and it still works... sort of. It only works for 1 textView. i now have 2 textViews but this fixes the problem for only one of them. Both are initialzed the EXACT same way and using the same methods and everything. The 2nd textView still has the issue that the first one had. Though i can change the colour of both normally, and their texts DO change but it only displays thechange for one of them

Comment: I have assigned the String value i  wanted to update the textview with to a final variable, and now it works. This is soooo strange. Why is this happening?